# Собственный итератор JAVA

Tags: java, итераторы

```
IterNap napis = new IterNap("prOgrAmoWanIe ObiEktOwe i Gui");

    for (char z: napis)
        System.out.print(z + " ");
```

В коде выше я создаю объект `napis` класса `IterNap`, а после в цикле for-each выписываю каждый символ. В результате должна получиться вот такая строка

```
p r O g r A m o W a n I e   O b i E k t O w e   i   G u i
```

Задача: написать реализацию класса `IterNap`, использовать массивы и коллекции запрещено.

Вообще не понимаю как это реализовать. Смог только создать класс `IterMap` и унаследоваться от `Itarable`, но как переопределить итератор? Прошу помощи.

Comment: Выложите сюда класс IterNap

Comment: Он пустой, там только конструктор.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/51FNH.png

Comment: Я заходил по всем этим ссылкам. Там нет ответов на мой вопрос

Answer (score 4):

Почитайте документацию по `Interface Iterator<E>` ([читать](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)), поймите, что ожидается от выполнения методов этого интерфейса (их контракт) и реализуйте. Ваш `IterNap` принимает строку в конструкторе, использовать массивы и коллекции нельзя, судя по вводу/выводу, вы будете итерироваться по строке (по символам строки). Полагаю, что для вашей задачи хватит реализовать 2 метода: `hasNext()` и `next()`. Ниже вариант сделанный на скорую руку и в нём есть что можно улучшить, но для понимания, как решать такие задачи достаточно.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class IterNap implements Iterable<Character> {

    // Строка по которой итерируемся
    private final String inputString;

    // Конструктор получающий строку
    public IterNap(String inputString) {
        this.inputString = inputString;
    }

    // Реализовали метод Iterable для получения итератора (в нашем случае это инстанс вложенного класса ImplIterator, имплементирующего интерфейс Iterator)
    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new ImplIterator();
    }

    // Класс ImplIterator, имплементирующий интерфейс Iterator
    private class ImplIterator implements Iterator<Character> {

        // Это текущий элемент в итераторе и одновременно счётчик
        int current = 0;

        // Возвращает true, если есть следующий элемент (символ)
        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if (current == inputString.length()) { // простая проверка - если текущий элемент равен количеству символов в строке, то есть
                                               // указвает на последний символ в строке, значит следущий элемент отсутствует и вернём false
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        // Возвращает следующий элемент в итерации (символ)
        @Override
        public Character next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            return inputString.charAt(current++);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        IterNap napis = new IterNap("prOgrAmoWanIe ObiEktOwe i Gui");

        for (char z : napis) {
            System.out.print(z + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

В целом задача простая: понять как работает итератор. А работает он очень просто:

```
public class IteratorNap implements Iterator<Character> {
    private String value;
    private int pos;

    public IteratorNap(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
       return pos < value.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Character next() {
       return value.charAt(pos++);
    }
}
```

Как видно у итератора есть 2 метода: `hasNext()`, который проверяет есть ли еще данные и `next()` который возвращает эти данные.

Имея этот класс уже можно составить замысловатую конструкцию перебора:

```
for (IteratorNap it = new IteratorNap("Hello world!"); it.hasNext(); ) {
    char character = it.next();
    System.out.print(character + " ");
}
```

Но чтобы избежать эту конструкцию и получить более знакомый формат перебора, нужно реализовать интерфейс `Iterable`:

```
public static class IterableNap implements Iterable <Character> {
    private String value;

    public IterableNap(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Character> iterator() {
        return new IteratorNap(this.value);
    }
}
```

Я думаю тут всё понятно без объяснений.

В итоге мы получаем следующее:

```
IterableNap nap = new IterableNap("Hello world!");

for(char character : nap) {
    System.out.print(character + " ");
}

>> H e l l o   w o r l d !
```